# Campus Tour Android

Tags: android

I need your help.

I want to make an android app project for my final research and it's a campus virtual tour app.

After I found a lot of references, I finally decided to build something similar to this app
[Yale Virtual Campus Tour](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.yc360.college.yaletour) (for example)

What kind of open source tools (IDE, frameworks, etc) I can use to build something like that?

PS: I'm not picky with the programming language, you can recommend me any tools as long as it's open source (I'm a student so I don't have much budget).

There's VR feature in that app but I'm not going to add VR. Just a simple tour app and my campus is in a single building, so it doesn't really need gps locator.

My priority is to build it fast and can be done in 3-4 months and the main target is for android devices (don't have to look native).

I avoid using Android studio, because based on my experience it would take more than 4 months to build this app using Android studio.

I really need your recommendation. Sorry for bad English, I'm not a native speaker.